# Delimiter to use within a query string value

Tags: string, query-string, delimiter

I need to accept a list of file names in a query string. ie:

```
http://someSite/someApp/myUtil.ashx?files=file1.txt|file2.bmp|file3.doc
```

Do you have any recommendations on what delimiter to use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If they're filenames, a good choice would be a character which is disallowed in filenames. Suggestions so far included `, | &` which are generally allowed in filenames and therefore might lead to ambiguities. `/` on the other hand is generally not allowed, not even on Windows. It is allowed in URIs, and it has no special meaning in query strings.

Example:

`http://someSite/someApp/myUtil.ashx?files=file1.txt|file2.bmp|file3.doc` is bad because it may refer to the valid file `file1.txt|file2.bmp`.

`http://someSite/someApp/myUtil.ashx?files=file1.txt/file2.bmp/file3.doc` unambiguously refers to 3 files.

Comment: This answer is mostly incorrect. The | character is not valid in URLs, per official specs, and may cause various problems if you attempt to use it. The & character is reserved in query strings to separate name/value pairs. The comma may be an OK choice, but more research is needed.

Comment: it is dangerous to assume | is not allowed in filenames. Linux allows any characters in filenames. but in Windows, yes, there are a handful of specific exclusions, which include |.

Comment: @DougS: I'm explaining why `|` is a bad choice with regard to filenames. It may also be a bad choice in URL's, I'm not even making a claim about that. So how does that make my answer incorrect?

Comment: I notice no one is disputing the use of "/"

Answer (score 32):

Having query parameters multiple times is legal, and the only way to guarantee no parsing problems in all cases:

```
http://someSite/someApp/myUtil.ashx?file=file1.txt&file=file2.bmp&file=file3.doc
```

The semicolon `;` must be URI encoded if part of a filename (turned to `%3B`), yet not if it is separating query parameters which is its reserved use.

See section 2.2 of [this rfc](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986):

> 2.2. Reserved Characters
>
> URIs include components and subcomponents that are delimited by
> characters in the "reserved" set.  These characters are called
> "reserved" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by
> the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the
> implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm.
> If data for a URI component would conflict with a reserved
> character's purpose as a delimiter, then the conflicting data must be
> percent-encoded before the URI is formed.
>
> ```
>  reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims
>
>  gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"
>
>  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
>              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
> ```

Comment: Your answer seems to have two parts. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 8):

I would recommend making each file its own query parameter, i.e.

```
myUtil.ashx?file1=file1.txt&file2=file2.bmp&file3=file3.doc
```

This way you can just use standard query parsing and loop

Answer (score 7):

Do you need to list the filenames as a string? 
Most languages accepts arrays in the querystring so you could write it like

```
http://someSite/someApp/myUtil.ashx?files[]=file1.txt&files[]=file2.bmp&files[]=file3.doc
```

If it doesn't, or you can't use for some other reason, you should stick to a delimiter that is either not allowed or unusual in a filename. Pipe (|) is a good one, otherwise you could urlencode an invisible character since they are quite easy to use in coding, but harder to actually include in a filename.

I usually use arrays when possible and pipe otherwise.

Comment: it is dangerous to assume | is not allowed in filenames. Linux allows any characters in filenames. but in Windows, yes, there are a handful of specific exclusions, which include |.

Answer (score 6):

I've always used double pipes "||".  I don't have any good evidence to back up why this is  a good choice other than 10 years of web programming and it's never been an issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is one common problem. How i handled it was: I created a method which accepted a list of strings, then found a character that was not in any of the strings. (I did this by a simple concatenation of the strings, then testing for various characters.) Once a character was found, concatenated all the strings together but also prepended the string with the separation character. So in the given question, one example wud be:
http://someSite/someApp/myUtil.ashx?files=|file1.txt|file2.bmp|file3.doc
and another wud be:
http://someSite/someApp/myUtil.ashx?files=,file1.txt,file2.bmp,file3.doc
But since i actually use a method that guarantees my separator character is not in the rest of the strings, it is safe. It was a bit of work to create the first time, but i've used it MANY times in various applications.

Comment: i don't know where my original code for this is. i did it years ago. maybe a decade ago, i don't even remember how long it has been. if i need this functionality again, i'd recode it. what i did in recent times (within last couple years), i just used Andrew Harry's approach: file1=aoeu.txt&file2=snth.txt&file3=aoeu.jpg Then i just looped infinitely until 'file'+n was not found in the querystring.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would consider using commas or semicolons.

Comment: Semicolon is a valid replacement for &, so is not a good choice: "The series of pairs is separated by the ampersand, '&' or semicolon, ';'." (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Structure)

Answer (score 0):

I would build on MSalters answer by saying, to generalize, the best delimiter is one that is invalid to the items in the list.  For example, if your list is prices, a comma is a bad delimiter because it can be confused with the values.  For that reason, as most these answers suggest, I think a good general purpose delimiter is probably "|" as it is rarely a valid value.  "/" is maybe not the best delimiter generally as it is valid for paths sometimes.